# Diagonal Cut on a text on the path of a svg line

Tags: html, css, d3.js, svg, svg-animate

I need a diagonal cut on the text. Whenever a svg line moves above the text, the text should be diagonally cut.
Is it possible to achieve this kind of scenario. ?
Below is the code.
And an image of what I what to achieve.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type="text/css">
h1{
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <svg height="210" width="500">
 <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
 <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 153);stroke-width:2">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      values="200 200;-150 -150;200 200"
      begin="0s"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
 </line>
 </svg>
<h1>OUR<br>WORK</h1>

 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version entirely in SVG.

```html
<html>
<head><title></title>
<style type="text/css">
h1{
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <svg height="210" width="500">
 <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
 <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(0, 0, 153);stroke-width:2">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
      type="translate"
      values="200 200;-150 -150;200 200"
      begin="0s"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
 </line>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip1">
         <polygon points="0, 0 200, 200, 0, 200"/>
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="clip2">
         <polygon points="0, 0 200, 0, 200, 200"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <text x="0" y="42" font-size="33px" font-weight="bold" clip-path="url(#clip1)">OUR<tspan x="0" dy="36">WORK</text>
    <text x="4" y="38" font-size="33px" font-weight="bold" clip-path="url(#clip2)">OUR<tspan x="4" dy="36">WORK</text>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```